# Create class that creates another class that can be overloaded (like excel - Thisworkbook.Worksheets)

Tags: c#

In Excel object model '**Thisworkbook**' is a class that has '**Worksheets**' class in it and can be **overloaded** with index or by sheet name. Moreover, '**Worksheets**' class also has some properties/methods that can be called with/without calling the constructor (default).

- E.g. MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name **'<-- by (int)**
- E.g. MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name **'<- by (string)**
- E.g. Msgbox Thisworkbook.Worksheets.Count '<- **'count property**

How can I create such class in **C#** that has another class in it and can be overloaded?
I have tried creating a public variable of the 2nd class in the 1st class but I can only call default constructor (or other - but just one at a time)

```
class A
{
    public B b = new B(); // <-- this is 1st constructor but how to overload ?
}

class B
{
    public B() // Default Constructor
    {
    }
    public B(int i) // Constructor 2
    {
    }
    public B(string s) // Constructor 3
    {
    }
    public int Count // Property
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------

class Main()
{

   A a = new A();
   a.b.Count(); // <-- THIS WORKS
   // a.b(1).Name; <-- HOW TO, USING THE SAME CLASS?
   // a.b("A").Name; <-- HOW TO, USING THE SAME CLASS?
}
```

I know that I have not created an object array - 1 or "A" that can be returned in this example, but I just need the concept (you got it right?). I have also seen few examples using List but I really want to know how I can achieve such object hierarchy in C#... (please excuse me if this is a wrong question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding operators.

What you're seeing is the **indexing operator** defined on the `Worksheets` class.
In C#, that would be called as `a.b[1]` or `a.b["2"]`.

You define it like this:

```
public SomeType this[int index] { get { ... } }
public SomeType this[string index] { get { ... } }
```